# How to make transition work while using the CSS background-clip property

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

So I have a gradient paragraph that I am using background-clip: text with, however, I want it to fade in when it appears. When I try to set a transition on the opacity, it doesn't fade in like expected, instead, it appears instantly. I would like opacity to transition from 0 to 1.

```js
let counter = 0;

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter = counter + 1;
  document.querySelector(`#line-${counter}`).style.opacity = 1;
});
```

```css
.text-container {
  color: #5ca17c;
  transition: 1s;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0ff1f, #0eff86);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.text {
  opacity: 0
 }
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="text" id="line-1">line 1</li>
    <li class="text" id="line-2">line 2</li>
    <li class="text" id="line-3">line 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I remove the `background-clip` property, things work as expected. How would I make this work with `background-clip: text`? I need the gradient to span the entire list instead of line by line.

Comment: A little confusing question .. do you need a smooth appearance of item text when you click?

Comment: Yes, apologies. I would like opacity to transition from 0 to 1 smoothly. If I remove background-clip it works as expected.

Comment: You haven't added the CSS `transition` property, so why would you expect it to transition?

Comment: transition: 1s is under the .text-container class.

Answer (score 1):

It works when you give the `.text` a transition

**Here's the code:**

```js
let counter = 0;

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter = counter + 1;
  document.querySelector(`#line-${counter}`).style.opacity = 1;
});
```

```css
.text-container {
  color: #5ca17c;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0ff1f, #0eff86);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.text {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
 }
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="text" id="line-1">line 1</li>
    <li class="text" id="line-2">line 2</li>
    <li class="text" id="line-3">line 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not fully working -- the bullets points fade in correctly but not the text for me.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with the text isn't fading in correctly?

Comment: It is just instantaneously appearing after 1s, instead of fading in like the bullet points are. Run the code snippet and click to see it happen.

Comment: I really don't know what you want. I took a close look at the snippet and I didn't see any problems. I did it exactly as you described. If you don't like it then just write **css transitions** on google and you're done. It's not that hard to do. If you still haven't found a solution then describe your problem properly. A transition with 1s from `opacity: 0;` to `opacity: 1;` is actually a fade in transition.